# Python restart program not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, restart

When creating a GUI using tkinter in python 2.7, i want the program to restart. It seemed simple enough, and after a short amoun of research I came upon the following code, which seemed to work:

```
python = sys.executable
os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

however, it has just stopped working, as in, the program runs perfectly the first time around, but then when restarting it says:

=============================== RESTART: Shell ==============================
.>>>

and nothing happens. If anyone knows any reason why i would be very appreciative, and any solutions to this problem would be a tremendous help.

UPDATE:
I tried running it in command line, however, the same issue occured however this time it said, "no such file or directory" when restarting, any ideas why?

Comment: Does `python = sys.executable` still give you a result? You're not actually checking it ...

Comment: Are you running your program in IDLE? Maybe you'd have better luck if you ran it from the command line.

Comment: I have just tried running it in cmd however, the issue still persists.

Comment: In my experience, managing program control flow by executing new processes tends to be a pretty brittle solution. When possible, try to accomplish this sort of thing using ordinary control flow statements. You can easily make your program run twice in a row using a for loop, for instance. Easier said than done in some cases: For instance, if you're eight layers deep in the function call stack, then you can't throw away the whole program state and start from scratch just with a `continue`. But it's almost always possible with careful high-level design and redesign.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! However, I am using Tkinter so a loop will stop me being able to close the program so...